# Ruby on Rails with chargify

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chargify

I want to integrate chargify to my rails app. I have user object and I want the user to be able to subscribe for one month and update the boolean column on user object. I prefer to use the API not hosted pages. How can I do that?

Is there any example for chargify on ruby on rails for handling subscriptions but with details about mvc for newbies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [thread](http://help.chargify.com/entries/20126343-rails-3-code-example-to-implement-chargify) and the Googles it looks like there is not a whole lot out there.

You could try looking at the Rails 2 example [here](https://github.com/npverni/chargify-demo) and converting it or use the [gem here](https://github.com/pengwynn/chargify) (gem "chargify", "~> 0.3.0").

I know none of this is aimed at newbies but the info seems to sparse.

Comment: Update: chargify maintain a gem that makes it really easy to work with their API from rails: https://github.com/chargify/chargify_api_ares

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.railsinside.com/elsewhere/371-chargify-rails-powered-recurring-billing-service-with-an-activeresource-api.html) might get you going. It seems that Chartify itself is written in Rails, and therfore their API is ruby code, which you can use...